# Different MySQL versions returns different result when have LEFT JOIN and ORDER in subquery

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have this query

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.code, rv.votes
FROM tbl_rhythms AS r
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT rhythm_id, votes
   FROM tbl_songs_rhythms
   WHERE song_id = 1
   ORDER BY votes DESC) AS rv
ON r.id = rv.rhythm_id
```

...which returns this result when executed in MySQL 5.6.20

```
3,Blues,blues,         2
4,Bollero,bollero,     1
1,Ballad,ballad,       NULL
2,Slow,slow,           NULL
5,Slow rocj,slowrock,  NULL
6,Disco,disco,         NULL
```

but when I execute the same query in MySQL 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

```
1,Ballad,ballad,       NULL
2,Slow,slow,           NULL
3,Blues,blues,         2
4,Bollero,bollero,     1
5,Slow rock,slowrock,  NULL
6,Disco,disco,         NULL
```

As you can see, the order is messed up.

Is it a bug of MySQL 5.5.40?

Comment: I would be very, very, very surprised if this were really true.  First, the `order by` in the subquery really has no impact on the `left join`.  My first guess is that the data is actually different on the two servers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has different results, but then you add "the order is messed up."

This is obviously true because the outer query has no `order by`.  And, it is the `order by` in the *outermost* `select` that determines the ordering.  You need to put the order by there:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.code, rv.votes
FROM tbl_rhythms r LEFT JOIN
     tbl_songs_rhythms rv
     ON r.id = rv.rhythm_id AND rv.song_id = 1
ORDER BY rv.votes DESC;
```

This also should make the query more efficient, because it is not materializing a subquery and it can use an in dex on `tbl_songs_rhythms(rhythm_id)` for the `join`.

As for why `balad,balad` would get `NULL` in one case but `1` in the other -- I think that would be a data issue and has nothing to do with the structure of this query.

Comment: I tried this with **same data** in both servers and the order is still messed up in MySQL 5.5.40. I also edit my question (the query results).

Comment: Yes, the data is different, so the queries has different result but what I want to show here is the **order is not correct**. I do know that if I change the query, it would work properly. But I there is many more queries like this in my project so I need to know the reason to fix it correctly.

Comment: @TrungDQ . . . The ordering of a result set is determined by the outermost `order by`.  That's the law of SQL and of pretty much every database.  If your older queries depend on the results being in a particular order, and there is no `order by` in the outer query, they are broken and need to be fixed.

Comment: Right, so the `LEFT JOIN` basically does not respect the order, but that still does not answer my question why did the results showed up different. Anyways thanks for your optimize query.

Comment: @TrungDQ . . . You are missing the point.  Repeat to yourself until you fully understand:  "The ordering of the result set is only determined by the `ORDER BY` clause for the entire query."  This is how SQL works.  The presence or absence of joins, aggregations, filters, and subqueries is not relevant.  The ordering is determined only by `ORDER BY` for the entire query.